# Can you wash a pop can or ( in my case ) a monster energy drink can in a dishwasher?

Tags: equipment, cleaning, kitchen-safety, dishwasher

Can you wash a pop can That os recealable but empty in the dishwasher or will it degrade?

Comment: It may or may not degrade, but it won't get clean on the inside.

Comment: Can I clarify what you want to do?  Do you mean wash a full can before you open it, perhaps to avoid ingesting any contaminant on the outside of the "ring pull", or do you mean wash the empty can after you have drunk it, perhaps to reuse for something?

Answer (score 7):

Dishwasher soap is highly alkaline, and highly alkaline solutions easily attack aluminum.

Based on my experience when I accidentally put some pan with aluminum parts in the dishwasher, the degradation appears as loss of the shiny aspect, which resembles a matte finish. Do it enough times and you will get a hole.

Comment: Besides what you already mentioned, dishwasher detergents contain grit to help the water scour the items to be cleaned.  It’s possible that it would strip off the paint on the can, especially those on the lower rack.  It’s also not going to be able to fully get into the can, and may toss the cans around in the dishwasher.  It definitely won’t be able to clean the insides as intended as there’s a small hole in a mostly closed container.